# Regex to accept atleast one alphabet one numeric char and one special Character

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to write a regex that accetps a string that has atleast 1 number 1 alphabet and 1 special character ,

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][@#$%^& .. and a bunch more]+$
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[...])/i
```

`[...]` should hold the special characters you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial , i am learning regex right now , looks like i have a biiiig journey ahead of me !

Comment: @Felix Kling just one more Q , how do i escape "\" ? i tried \\ \\\

Comment: @Deepak: ``\\`` should be fine.

Comment: @Felix Kling hey its matching ab12 also , but ab#$ fails

Comment: @Deepak: I don't know what you are doing, but it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6LPXH/ (`ab12` does not match).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qwYvM/ I ran JSlInt ^ and / were not escaped , i rectified it but still ab12 is true ,

Comment: @Deepak: You actually don't have to escape `^`, `(` and `)` inside the character class. The problem was `)-_`. This matches every character between `)` and `_`, which includes numbers and letters. Inside a character class, `-` indicates are range, as long as it is not at the beginning or at the end of the class. You have to escape it: `)\-_` (or put it at the beginning/end), and then it works: http://jsfiddle.net/qwYvM/1/

Comment: Yep Figured out that atleast from my sied by trial and error :( , i was trying to find out which char i needed to escape and i put -_ and rest of it at beginning and everything worked , but didnt know the reason , your explanation clears out my doubt , thanks a lot !

Comment: @Deepak: You're welcome :) FWIW, here is the ASCII table and you can see the the range of characters `)` and `_` include: http://www.asciitable.com/ Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = "1a$";
item.match(/^[0-9][a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z0-9\s\t\n]$/)
```

That should work

Comment: the string "b1&" does not match your regex but is valid due to question

Comment: @Felix Kling, at least one number, letter *and* special character.

Comment: @katspaugh: Yeah that's what I meant actually :D Thanks.

Comment: @all :p yeah, I made both the assumption that it was in a certain order and the baseless assumption that it was only one of each. :P  Oh well... Think I'll delete the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 little regex to accomplish that easily (it's more readable) :

- [0-9]
- [a-zA-Z]
- [-_$@...]