# Requiring Letters and Numbers in form field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a form and I need to require letters and numbers. All the solutions I have seen, simply allow only letters and numbers but do not require both.

I have this Regex: `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/` which allows one or the other. How can I make this a requirement, meaning the text must contain at least a number.

Thanks my friends.

Guy

Comment: `/^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i`

Comment: Look for "regular expression look-ahead"

Comment: Yet another password validator?

Comment: I am pointing you to this----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026283/regex-to-accept-atleast-one-alphabet-one-numeric-char-and-one-special-character

Comment: @devnull: This is not for a password: Just a filed the uses numbers and letters combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To break this down, we're requiring at least 2 characters, a letter and a number. In the code we start with the possibility of an alpha-numeric character. I'm not using `\w` because it also allows `_` characters. In the group we have an or that looks for either a letter before a number, or a number before a letter. Then after the group we're requiring if anything exists that it also be alpha-numeric.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Za-z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$/i
```

As a recommendation, it's always best to use a server-side language as your front-line defense when validating a form instead of a Javascript-only approach. The reasons:

1. Someone can disable Javascript
2. The server needs to be protected from malicious attack (SQL or XSS injection)
3. Someone can bypass your form altogether by directly linking to the handler (if you're not requiring a valid referrer)
4. Some browsers like Lynx do not use Javascript, so it's not user friendly for people who need to use screen reading devices

Comment: Well said: I have already finished the C# validation that kicks in if the user disable JavaScript. This is simply for usability purposes. Otherwise you are right, JS Validation is like a Bank with no Security Guards. :)